# FormBuilder submission and add to group

Tags: formbuilder

Once I've created a form in FormBuilder form and exposed it to the front end, how can I wrap some rules around it once a submission is sent?  For example, add the user to a group, notify these people that form has been submitted, that kind of thing.

I'm using it to collect volunteer interest, including from anonymous users.  Once they submit, I'd like to add that contact to a group and notify the volunteer coordinator.

Any insight appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a "volunteer inquiry" activity type and configure the form to log that activity. The benefit is you know when they inquired, not just they are a volunteer. Yes, the group added date would have that but activities are the best way to track interactions. When you assign an activity, it automatically notifies the assignee.

[image]

Then, create a CiviRule to trigger on the *activity is added* trigger targeting the activity source with a *Add Contact to a Group* action.

[image]

You optionally can add an additional CiviRule targeting the activity assignee to send an email notification (via the [emailapi extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/emailapi)) to the volunteer coordinator.

[image]

This may be preferred if you want to easily customize the message of the notification. If so, then you'd want to disable the default notification at [Display Preferences](https://%20Display%20Preferences).

[image]

Comment: That is an elegant solution my friend.  I greatly appreciate it.