# Confusion about CiviRules > Trigger for 'Source', 'Target', 'Assignee'

Tags: civirules, activity

This question comes off the back of a (now answered) question I asked previously about [FormBuilder and email routing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43538/formbuilder-submission-and-add-to-group).

I setup a CiviRule to trigger and perform some actions when a specific activity is created.  It works.  The problem is....I don't know why.

Under LINKED TRIGGER, what are the difference between 'For all targets', 'Activity Targets', 'Activity Assignee', and 'Activity Source'?  How will changing this effect the Rule?  I'm concerned that my lack of understanding means it won't trigger in certain scenarios, or something is going to be routed somewhere I don't want it to go.

I couldn't find any documentation explaining it (or I'm too dumb to have understood what I read) :)

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some definition mapping to help here. All activities have [3 possible roles](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/activities/). See in parentheses the civirule terminology.

- **added by (source)** the person who added this Activity, or the contact if they carried out the Activity themselves via the website
- **with contact(s) (target)** the contacts in your database that are the subject of the Activity.
- **assigned to (assignee)**  the person (usually within your organisation) that will carry out (or has carried out) the Activity

In your case, the source (because it is web-based) and the target is the volunteer signing up, which is who you want effected by the CiviRule (e.g. add to Volunteer group). It automatically uses the source by default but you'll want to also have the target be the volunteer signup as well for comprehensive reporting purposes. The source may be a back-end user adding that someone wants to volunteer and not the volunteer themselves, so best to use the target as the trigger.

Comment: Andy, that's twice you've helped me out in as many days.  Genuine big appreciation for the clear concise responses.  This clears up my confusion.  Thank you.